# Validation error while inputting a record into Postgres

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I have created a table using the following query,

```
CREATE TABLE user_account (
user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
user_name VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR ( 255 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
allow BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);
```

Following is my models.py

```
class AccountsInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_account"

    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    user_name = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    created_on = Column(DateTime)
    allow = Column(Boolean)
```

Following is my schema.py

```
class AccountsInfoBase(BaseModel):
    user_name: str
    password: str
    email: str
    created_on: str
    allow: bool

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class AccountsCreate(AccountsInfoBase):
    password = str


class AccountsInfo(AccountsInfoBase):
    user_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

I use the following code to create an user,

```
def create_user(db: Session, user: schemas.AccountsCreate):
    db_user = models.AccountsInfo(user_name=user.user_name, password=user.password, email=user.email,created_on=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time())),allow=True)
    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_user)
    return db_user
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following error,

> raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
> pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for
> AccountsInfo response -> created_on   str type expected
> (type=type_error.str)

what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_) pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for AccountsInfo response -> created_on str type expected (type=type_error.str)

In your table the created_on is DateTime.

```py
class AccountsInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_account"

    created_on = Column(DateTime)
```

But you declared as `str` in your Pydantic model.

```py
class AccountsInfoBase(BaseModel):
    created_on: str
```

Declare your field as [datetime in Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#datetime-types) model. Also SQLAlchemy gives you ability to create datetime automatically.

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
```